# Profile photos from AD show in profile, not in Org Browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, organization-browser

We are syncing AD with SharePoint 2010, and the photos loaded from AD shows up in the user profiles. But, while the Org browser shows the hierarchy fine, it does not show the photos.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you issue with the picture size.
Please browse the Profile Pictures library and make sure each user has three pictures and these show a correct picture.

- LThumb
- MThumb
- Sthumb

Follow this blog for more information and fix. http://www.sharepointfire.com/MyBlog/2014/06/sharepoint-2010-organization-chart-is-not-showing-correct-pictures/

Answer (score 0):

Try running this powershell command against the Central Admin application. It must be run with the same account running the User Profile Service

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
#Check Services -> AppFabric Caching Service & Central Admin -> UPS -> Permissions
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation http://<server>:2000/
```

After which, you have to do another AD sync and then the thumbnails will be populated